# Convert PySpark Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe fails on timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I create my pyspark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, BinaryType, ArrayType, StringType, TimestampType
    input_schema = StructType([
            StructField("key", StringType()),
            StructField("headers", ArrayType(
                StructType([
                    StructField("key", StringType()),
                    StructField("value", StringType())
                ])
            )),
            StructField("timestamp", TimestampType())
        ])
    
        input_data = [
            ("key1", [{"key": "header1", "value": "value1"}], datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
            ("key2", [{"key": "header2", "value": "value2"}], datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
            ("key3", [{"key": "header3", "value": "value3"}], datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
        ]
    
        df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, input_schema)
```

I want to use Pandas' `assert_frame_equal()`, so I want to convert my dataframe to a Pandas dataframe.

`df.toPandas()` will throw `TypeError: Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead.`

How can I successfully convert the "timestamp" column in order to not lose detail of the datetime value? I need them to remain to `2023-01-01 00:00:00` and not `2023-01-01`.

Comment: Could you share some more details about the code, such as your imports and your spark variable?

Comment: Updated but nothing special. Running local version of pyspark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df = df.withColumn("timestamp", date_format("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).toPandas()
```

Now I was able to use

```
assert_frame_equal(df, test_df)
```

successfully. It did not lose precision.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote some generic logic to do this programmatically in case you don't want to hardcode the column headers for whichever columns are timestamps:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

def convert_to_pandas(spark_df):
    """
    This function will safely convert a spark DataFrame to pandas.
    """
    # Iterate over columns and convert each timestamp column to a string
    timestamp_cols = []
    for column in spark_df.schema:
        if column.dataType == TimestampType():
            # Append column header to list
            timestamp_cols.append(column.name)
            # Set column to string using date_format function
            spark_df = spark_df.withColumn(
                column.name,
                date_format(column.name, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    # Convert to a pandas DataFrame and reset timestamp columns
    pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
    for column_header in timestamp_cols:
        pandas_df[column_header] = pandas_df[
            column_header].astype("datetime64[ns]")

    return pandas_df
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, solved it by downgrading pandas to 1.5.3. It seems like the changes in pandas 2 break compatibility with pyspark (tested with pyspark 3.3).

If you're using pip you should be able to fix it with `pip install pandas==1.*`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this problem with PySpark 3.4.1 and Pandas 2.x.

After upgrading to **PySpark 3.5.0**, with Pandas 2.1.2, the problem is solved, just a deprecation warning appeared:

```
FutureWarning: is_datetime64tz_dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Check `isinstance(dtype, pd.DatetimeTZDtype)` instead.
```